# Report Writer save as Crystal Reports rpt file

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, report

Is there any open source Report Writer (preferably with an Eclipse plugin) that can also be saved as a Crystal Report .rpt file.

The reason:
Due to workload constraints from the ERP Data Management team, I will be connecting to an ERP datasource **temporarily** so we can access data and produce a report for our users until they ERP team has the time to generate the Crystal Report they use from the ERP (6-9 months).

Our ideal solution would allow us to use a report writer to generate the reports we need and then save it in .rpt format which would cut down on the time till it can be deployed in the ERP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a copy of Crystal Reports Developer?

- It's relatively cheap ($400 USD).  For a 6-9 month delay, imho, this is not an excessive price.
- It has an eclipse plugin: http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalreports-eclipse/index.epx
- There is also a free Viewer: http://www.sap.com/solutions/sap-crystal-solutions/query-reporting-analysis/sapcrystalviewer/index.epx

Comment: I agree the purchase of the Crystal License would be the easiest way to solve the problem.  The problem is that everything is only a few hundred dollars each and I work in the public sector so our budgets are set on a two year cycle (and they always get cut to the bone anyway) AND it seems like overkill to create 2-3 reports.  Thanks for the answer

Comment: Ah, yes, the public sector dilemma.  In that case, don't use anything Crystal.  Would a plain Excel file suffice? You can set up an Excel file to display all results from an Access query. It's not very pretty, but you can configure it any way you want and you can script it with VBA.

Comment: Our users would be thrilled to have a simple excel output but the ability to allow an outside agency to have an ODBC connection is controversial and temporary.  yes I know it is ridiculous.  It is not like the reports that are generated by the ERP are very fancy but The ERP system will only accept CR Reports.

Comment: There's no need to give anyone an outside ODBC connection with the Excel method.  You could even just copy&paste the data into Excel, but you know your system better than I do. As for the .rpt format, it's propietary as far as I know, so it's either a Crystal product or the highway.  Good luck.